# How to read and generate pdf in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a code segment in Express.js that looks like this:

```
var pdf = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
pdf.end();

// Send the pdf to the client.
var file = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
file.pipe(res);
```

And I can see that the file is actually created in the server, but when I ready it with `createReadStream`, I get that its size is 0. So something gets corrupted. Any idea what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is not corrupted, you're treating the code as synchronous, yet is asynchronous.

You have to wait until the file is fully written, then you can read it. Anyway you don't need to write it to a file to send the content, if you don't need the file to persist on disk, you can just pipe it to `res`.

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);

const pdf = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdf.pipe(res);
```

If you wish to save it to a file, and then read it, you can do the following:

```
const write = fs.createWriteStream('./basics.pdf');
pdfDoc.pipe(write);

write.on('finish', () => {
   fs.createReadStream('./basics.pdf')
      .pipe(res); // 
});

pdfDoc.end();
```

Comment: You're welcome, added how to do it if you need persistence.